# How to let user only delete their details and no one elses php

Tags: php, sql, database

I created a very basic site where a user logs in and then has access to a table that they can edit. I want the user to be able to only delete their own details and no one elses, and I don't know what i'm supposed to add to the delete page so it only deletes the details of logged in user and doesn't delete anyone else's. At the moment it doesn't delete any details.

This is my register page

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "pconfig.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: plogin.php");
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="plogin.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is my login page

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: allcontacts.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "pconfig.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: allcontacts.php");
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="pregister.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This my contact page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Display Contacts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Display all records from Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Users</h2>

<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr.No.</td>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>

<?php

include "pconfig.php"; // Using database connection file here

$records = mysqli_query($link,"select * from users"); // fetch data from database

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['password']; ?></td>    
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr> 
<?php
}
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and finally my delete page

```
<?php

include "pconfig.php"; // Using database connection file here



$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string
if($param_username == "$id") {
   $del = mysqli_query($link,"delete from users where id = '$id'"); // delete query
mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
    header("location:allcontacts.php"); // redirects to all records page
    exit;
}
else
{
 echo "Error deleting record"; // display error message if not delete
}

?>
```

Comment: Please provide only the *minimal code necessary* to clarify your question. Nobody's gonna read all this…

Comment: Yes, a bit too much code. But it allows me to see that you store the user id in the session. You should use that to delete data belonging to that user, and not an user id given as an URL parameter.

Comment: `// Password is correct, so start a new session  session_start();` that will actually generate a warning in the logs saying session already started and then re-use the session. But I dont think that is actually a problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
include "pconfig.php"; // Using database connection file here


$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string

if($_SESSION["id"]!==$id){// display error message if user is not same
    echo "You need to delete your own record"; 
    exit; 
}

$del = mysqli_query($link,"delete from users where id = '$id'"); // delete query
mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
header("location:allcontacts.php"); // redirects to all records page
exit;
?>
```

**What you need to do is to add session_start() function on the above of the delete page**

- use this $_SESSION["id"] session as you have assigned in login page
- always check / compare logic before doing any operation so your code will be remain small, smart, simple ,readable and fast.